# Disable Exclusive Mode for all audio devices in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, audio, settings, device

I need to configure audio devices a large number of PCs.

I am stuck on how to Disable Exclusive Mode, "allow applications to take exclusive-mode of this device"

1. I can disable all the media devices:

`Get-PnpDevice -class "MEDIA" | ForEach-Object {Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $_.InstanceID -Confirm:$false}`

2. I can enable the desired devices:

`Get-PnpDevice -Class Media | where FriendlyName -like "*NVIDIA High Definition Audio*" | where Status -eq "OK" | ForEach-Object {  Disable-PnpDevice -instanceid $_.instanceid -Confirm:$false  }`

3. I can set the default audio device (playback/recording) leveraging AudioDeviceCmdlets.
4. I can even set the sound reduction to 0 through the registry

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio] "UserDuckingPreference"=dword:00000003`

5. But I cannot find an API or a data structure that corresponds to where the state is changed and how?

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are available in the registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx}\Properties
```

(change XXX by the GUID of your default record device)

The names of the keys are:

```
{b3f8fa53-0004-438e-9003-51a46e139bfc},3    
{b3f8fa53-0004-438e-9003-51a46e139bfc},4
```

The value can be 0 or 1.

This correspond to the check box "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device" and "Give exclusive mode applications priority"

But those key are owned by system account and cant be edited easily with a script.

If you are OK to use external program, a nirsoft sofware utility can do the job:

[Nirsoft SoundVolumeView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html)

You can use it from cli:

```
SoundVolumeView.exe /SetExclusivePriority "XXXXX" 0
SoundVolumeView.exe /SetAllowExclusive "XXXXXX" 0
```

(XXX can be ID or name of the record device)

Answer (score 0):

I came here because of a similar question.

I think 3rd party tools make it easier, because one does not need to search the registry for all related keys of audio settings you want to change quickly.
But it seems that Nirsoft tools like VolumeView mentioned above could be a security risk. See https://borncity.com/win/2020/04/16/dll-hijacking-vulnerabilities-in-nirsoft-tools/

I will try AudioDeviceCmdlets, to be found at Github. It serves the same purpose.